# unordered lists across browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, html-lists

I'm having some trouble formatting an unordered list to work properly across all browsers. The below looks fine in Chrome, but strange in IE and Firefox.

This is pretty simple, I know, but I'm new to this and can't seem to get it quite right.

Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<br>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<br>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<br>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<br>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<br>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<br>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    }

#rightcolumn {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: First of all, the <br> does nothing. You can remove that. Because every `li` is a block element and has by-itself a break in it.

What do you except and what goes wrong?

Comment: Your markup is invalid.  Only li elements can be children of ul and ol elements.  Invalid markup causes all sorts of unexpected problems because the browser tries to "fix" it for you.

Comment: Wow - thanks so much everyone. This was my first post on StackOverflow (and as you can see I'm kind of new to this in general) and the responses were so quick! Going to try it now, will let you know if everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
ul li{
    padding-bottom:1em;
}
```

instead of `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

you have to code it with valid HTML `<br>` is not a valid element in `<ul>`.

Also `<li>` is a block element so its allways fill the whole line so you dont need the `<br>`

My Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/9jKvW/

HTML:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>

<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>

<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>

<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="rightcolumn">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background:red;
    }

#rightcolumn {
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background:silver;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I very much appreciate it! One more thing: in IE, I'm getting some weird formatting of the first bullet (and I lose the space between the level 2 header and the list, which I should be able to solve with padding?). Here's a screenshot: http://s15.postimg.org/dxau16urf/IE_UL_issues.png

Any ideas? I'm sure this is probably a simple issue and I just don't know how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: look at this please : http://jsfiddle.net/9jKvW/3/ its based on the first example and work in IE 9. Its correct to use padding that the space between the level 2 header and the list you also cut try to solve this with margin or only with the hight of 'h2' and a fixed font-size